# I am getting the following error in my code: "'_VirtualList' object is not callable"

Tags: pypdf, python-pdfreader

This is the code:

```
import os
from openpyxl import Workbook
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

input_folder = r"C:\Users\91620\OneDrive\Desktop\Final Year Project\case laws (2)\New folder (2)"
output_file = r"C:\Users\91620\OneDrive\Desktop\Final Year Project\sentemental.xlsx"

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for i, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(input_folder)):
    if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
       filepath = os.path.join(input_folder, filename)
       with open(filepath, "rb") as f:
           pdf = PdfReader(f)
           readerpdf=len(pdf.pages())
           for page in range(readerpdf):
               text = pdf.getPage(page).extractText()
               ws.cell(row=page+1, column=i+1).value = text

wb.save(output_file)
```

This is the error I am receiving:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [9], line 16
     14 with open(filepath, "rb") as f:
     15     pdf = PdfReader(f)
---> 16     readerpdf=len(pdf.pages())
     17     for page in range(readerpdf):
     18         text = pdf.getPage(page).extractText()

TypeError: '_VirtualList' object is not callable
```

I want the pdf files text in the column of a excel sheet

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! So, the reason you received an error is actually explained by the Traceback. On line 16, there is a non-callable object that is being called. There are 2 objects that are being called on line 16: `len()` and `pages()`. You know that `len()` is callable, so the non-callable object must be `pages`.

Comment: @Übermensch That is exactly the right answer. I think you should make it an answer

Comment: @Nayan: Please move to pypdf. PyPDF2 is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you received an error is actually explained by the Traceback. On line 16, there is a non-callable object that is being called. There are 2 objects that are being called on line 16: `len()` and `pages()`. You know that `len` is callable (as it is a built-in function), so the non-callable object must be `pages`.

Simply remove the parentheses, so that you have `pdf.pages`.